# Update statement is not updating the right values in the database

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update `UnitinStock` and `Shipped Date` of products based on these conditions.

1. When the `Shipped date is null` and
2. When `Quantity < Unit in stock`.

But my query is updating `Shipped date` of the orders where `Shipped date is null` e but it is not satisfying `Quantity < Unit in stock`. As in, it is updating the null values to current date even when the `Quantity > Unit in stock`

How do I satisfy these 2 conditions and update columns:

```
update products,orderdetails,orders
set 
    products.UnitsInStock = (products.UnitsInStock - orderdetails.Quantity), 
    ShippedDate = current_date()
where 
    products.ProductID = orderdetails .ProductID 
    and orders.OrderID = orderdetails.OrderID
    and (ShippedDate is null and orderdetails.Quantity < UnitsInStock) 
    and  orders.OrderID = 11039
```

Comment: post some data of both tables

Comment: If you have several products in your order, it is sufficent that *one* of those products satisfies your condition, not *all*. Can that be the problem here? (But as Rakesh said, adding some sample data might clarify this).

Comment: For clarity's sake use explicit joins and qualify columns with table names so we can see where they come from

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic is okay.  I don't really understand the data model -- why is `ShippedDate` in `products` and not in `orderdetails`, for instance.  However, that is what the query specifies.

I observe that you do not need the `orders` table for the query.  So you can simplify the query.  You can also use explicit `join`s and table aliases so it is more readable:

```
update products p join
       orderdetails od
       on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
    set p.UnitsInStock = (p.UnitsInStock - od.Quantity), 
        p.ShippedDate = current_date()
where p.ShippedDate is null and
      od.Quantity < p.UnitsInStock and
      od.OrderID = 11039;
```

Comment: hey shipped date is in orders table, that is why I use orders table